# How to fix the error as 'tf_utils module not found'

Tags: python, package

I am using jupyter notebook for running python commands using the below code.

```
from tf_utils import load_dataset, random_mini_batches, convert_to_one_hot, predict
```

I get an error saying  `No module named 'tf_utils'`. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to install tensorflow-utils https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-utils/ or https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow not really sure which one you want.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that your question comes with Deep Learning course taught by Andrew Ng. 
The `tf_utils` here is different from `tensorflow-utils`, `tf_utils.py` is written by course staff. It is for that assignment only.

in your assignment notebook, you can click on "File" -> "Open..." at the top menu bar, and download that `tf_utils.py` to import it.